# How to add subname in profile?

Tags: support

[image]

The above is a user from Stack Overflow. How can I add a subname like ***Data Wrangler*** above? I don't see an option in my profile preferences to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only available on SO. Here's a feature request asking for it on other SE sites: [Getting Stack Overflow like Title field on other Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329778/270345)